# PHP login credentials are not being validate even though they are correct

Tags: php, authentication

Beginner question. I need to create a admin login for a blog but I'm having trouble getting it to accept the credentials. The login name is "user" and the password is "pwed" just for testing purposes. When I try to login it says my credentials are invalid even though they aren't. If successful, it just simply moves on to the admin page. It should be pretty simple mistake, which I'm looking over, but I was hoping maybe one of you could help me out.

Here's the login form

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
                <p>
                    <label for="name">Account Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" /><br/>
                    <label for="name">Password:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="password" id="name" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Next &gt;" />
                </p>
            </form>
```

Here's the PHP

```
<?php

        /* Check to see if there's a form submission */
        if (array_key_exists('Submit1', $_POST)) { // each page needs a different name for the submit button
            session_start();

            // clear any existing session variables because this is the very first page of the survey
            $_SESSION = array();


            /* set required fields */
            //  must be an array, even if only one item is required
            //  if no fields are required, an empty array is needed. Otherwise, in_array() later in the script will generate an error
            $required = array('name', 'password');



            $_SESSION['missing'] = array();

            // process the $_POST variables and save user input in the $_SESSION array
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                // assign to temporary variable and strip whitespace if not an array
                $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
                // if empty and required, add to $_SESSION['missing'] array
                if (empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)) {
                    array_push($_SESSION['missing'], $key);
                }
                // otherwise, assign to a variable of the same name as $key
                else {
                    $_SESSION[$key] = $temp;
                }
            }
            // if no required fields are missing, redirect to the next page
            if (!$_SESSION['missing']) {

              if  ($_SESSION['name'] == "user" && $_SESSION['password'] == "pwed"){
                  // set a variable to control access to other pages, this variable will be checked on all other survey pages
                  $_SESSION['access'] = true;

                  header('Location: svar02.php');
                  exit;

              }
                else {
                    echo "We're sorry your login details seem to be incorrect";
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "It seems you've left a field blank";
            }
            //}
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Your `action=""` attribute in your form tag is empty. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes, I left it blank because the form sits in the same page as the php script. Do I still need to add index.php to the action attribute even though they're on the same page?

Comment: No, if your php script is in the same place you can leave it empty. I think you could even remove the attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the following bit

```
$required = array('name', 'password');
```

It's requiring a field named `name` but your form has `login` so try:

```
$required = array('login', 'password');
```

Comment: Hey @aharen it was this, thanks so much man I knew it was going to be something simple and stupid as this. Oh well, you live you learn! Thanks so much! Have a happy holidays!

Comment: @CodyCarmichael Glad i could be of help, when i began with PHP i don't know how many times i've made this same mistake :) Happy Holidays!